# Issue with sequence why two entity are sharing the same sequence when generating schema with hbm2ddl ?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-annotations, hbm2ddl

I am using `hbm2ddl` in my hibernate based application to generate the db schema. The value of `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` property is `create-drop`.

I am using `@Entity` annotations for my POJO classes.

```
@Entity 
public class testTable1 {
     @Id     
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
     Long id; 
}

@Entity 
public class testTable2 {
     @Id     
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
     Long id; 
}
```

However on executing the code I keep getting continuously incremental Id values. e.g. for 2 tables the Id (i.e. Prim Key) should start each with 1. But after inserting records in `Table 1`, the sequence goes from next value for `Table 2`. It should start again from 1 for table 2.
I tried `GenerationType.SEQUENCE` & `GenerationType.AUTO`. nothing works :-(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using the Global sequence generator that hibernate provide by default when no generator is provided as specifed by the JPA Spec. To have a private generator you should declare a private generator with the annotation `@SequenceGenerator` and set the `generator` attribute of the `@GeneratedValue` annotation

Extracted from javadoc

> [@GeneratedValue](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html#generator%28%29)
>   (Optional) The name of the primary key generator to use as specified
>   in the SequenceGenerator or TableGenerator annotation.
>
> Defaults to the id generator supplied by persistence provider.
>
> [SequenceGenerator](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/SequenceGenerator.html)
>   This annotation defines a primary key generator that may be referenced by name when a
>   generator element is specified for the GeneratedValue annotation. A
>   sequence generator may be specified on the entity class or on the
>   primary key field or property. The scope of the generator name is
>   global to the persistence unit (across all generator types).
>
> Example:
>
> `@SequenceGenerator(name="EMP_SEQ", sequenceName="private_sequence")`

Hibernate recommends that new projects use hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=true as the new generators are more efficient and closer to the JPA 2 specification semantic

[Section 1.3. Properties](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#ann-setup-properties)
[2.2.3. Mapping identifier properties](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-identifier)

**Complete example**

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name="PRIVATE_SEQ", sequenceName="private_sequence")
public class test {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="PRIVATE_SEQ")
    Long id;
}
```

Comment: True and I would like to add that if you want to set initial value and allocation size , you need to include hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=true. Then you just need to use @SequenceGenerator like this : @SequenceGenerator(initialValue=1, allocationSize=1 , name="PRIVATE_SEQ", sequenceName="private_sequence") or whatever values you need to give.

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin can i use the same same sequence generator for multiple entity as you said above and get uniform exclusive id values in each entity?  I mean each entity id will start with 1 and get increment by 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
 @Entity
    public class MyEntity2 {
        
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="myentity2_seq")
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "myentity2_seq",sequenceName = "myentity2_seq_table")
        private int id;

    @Column(length = 100)
    private String name;
//setters & getters ...
}
```

In the Database, it will create **myentity2_seq_table** Table for maintaining ids. we can customize table creation using initialValue = 100, allocationSize = 10 in SequenceGenerator.

Answer (score 0):

In **Hibernate 5.2**,

I had tried Joel Hudon's answer, but don't know why it doesn't work.

I found some shorter codes to solve it.

[3.2. The annotated entity Java class](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/quickstart/html_single/#hibernate-gsg-tutorial-annotations-entity)

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator="increment")
@GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy = "increment")
public int id;
```

It could give out unique sequence number.

Hope it helps.